# Force FileVault to use 256-bit key encryption

Tags: macos, mojave, filevault

Is there a way to use 256-bit key encryption for macOS system?

I’ve tried formatting system partition myself with bigger key size APFS, but macOS installer actually reverted this as it asks for user password now on login screen, not “disk password” on boot.

Comment: Might be useful - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault

Comment: @slm not sure what should I see there. The page is poorly written in details, it lacks technical information like key sizes at all

Comment: The comment on that page stating that FileVault2 defaults to a 256 bit key. I was also able to find this doc from Apple - https://www.apple.com/business/resources/docs/macOS_Security_Overview.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most documentation I'm finding seems to indicate that the key's used in macOS 10.9 and higher use a 256 bit key by default.

> #### Encryption and authentication support
>
> FileVault 2 uses the Advanced
>   Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm, which delivers robust
>   protection for stored data. Until mid-2013, it only supported the use
>   of 128-bit keys, not 256-bit keys. Although 128-bit keys are
>   technically acceptable in many environments, organizations are rapidly
>   moving toward 256-bit keys to thwart emerging threats.
>
> The latest versions of Mac OS X, starting with 10.9, support 256-bit
>   AES keys, so organizations wishing to enable FileVault 2 on legacy
>   systems should be cautious about the 128-bit key strength present in
>   older Mac OS X versions, Lion (10.7) and Mountain Lion (10.8).

*Reference: [Apple FileVault 2: Full disk encryption software overview](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/feature/Apple-FileVault-2-Full-disk-encryption-software-overview)*

This PDF and the Wikipedia page seem to indicate this as well.

- [macOS Security - Overview for IT 2018](https://www.apple.com/business/resources/docs/macOS_Security_Overview.pdf)
- [Wikipedia - FileVault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault)