# External Hard Drive Encryption

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption

How to check if external hard drive is encrypted and type of encryption (128,256-bit)?

Comment: The first thing, if your external disk is encrypted, when you plug it and open it, a password is required.

Comment: What I had meant was when I use 'diskutil apfs list'  it lists volumes, but some of them miss rows with 'Encryption' field information. I was wondering if I could get information on key size.

Comment: You can try `diskutil info diskXsY`

Comment: @Jean_JD that shows FileVault Yes for me and not a specific key length or implementation.

Comment: But if encryption is run on >=10.9, FileVault default key is 256 bit. So if FileVault = Yes = 256 bit (I assume).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple encrypts disks with APFS currently and before that using Core Storage. You can get security information from the security white paper:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/welcome/web

I believe macOS uses 256 key length across the board, but can’t find that from the command line yet.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/data-protection-overview-secf6276da8a/web

Open the terminal if you prefer command line solutions - these two commands will dump all encrypted volumes:

```
diskutil apfs list
diskutil cs list
```

If you prefer a graphical tool, you can open the Disk Utility (use spotlight or open the Utilities folder within the Applications folder) to inspect each drive as you connect them.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/encrypt-protect-a-storage-device-password-dskutl35612/mac

Comment: And how to get information on key size?

Comment: I’ve edited this as best as I can find documented @Noz_Char I believe it’s 128 + 128 at the shortest key length for key plus cipher but can’t yet be certain.

Comment: Thank you @bmike!

Found this also:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356638/force-filevault-to-use-256-bit-key-encryption